# Fill table to SubForm ACCESS vba

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have application MS Access and  have path connect from another machine via IP,
How can I get all the list of records on SubForm?

```
Sub Load_All_User()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rst As Object
Dim strConnection As String
Dim strSql As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & "\\172.16.25.5\ACC\" & "test_connect.mdb"
strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbUser"
cn.Open strConnection
Set rst = cn.Execute(strSql)

If rst.BOF And rst.EOF Then
MsgBox "No data found"
Exit Sub
Else
    Child7.SourceObject=??????????????
End If

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this `Set Child7.Form.Recordset = rst.Recordset`

Comment: There was an error " OBject doesn't support property or method"
Please check again help me.

Comment: You want to display records in subform? Can't you just set a link with Linked Table Manager? Then set form's RecordSource property in design? https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/794622-linked-table-manager-ip-addressing

Comment: It should be `Set Child7.Form.Recordset = rst` I just checked and it works

Comment: The expression you entered refers an object that is closed or doesn't exist.

Comment: If the code is behind Child7, then try `Set Me.Recordset = rst`.